# Test framework for Spark Application validations

Tags: hadoop, testing, apache-spark

I am looking for your suggestions/help in testing framework for one of our Spark application.
We have a spark application which processes the input data from HDFS and pushes the processed output data to HDFS. We are planning to automate the process of testing this spark application.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to automate the testing or whether any framework available for testing spark applications/jobs.

-Sri

Answer (score 0):

Spark code can be checked without any additional Spark-related frameworks. Just set configuration master to "local":

```
val config = new SparkConf().setMaster("local")
```

Computer file system is used as HDFS by default. And such approach will work in usual test frameworks (ScalaTest, etc).

Note: SparkContext must be declared as singleton for all tests.